# How to localize iOS 14 widget's name (CFBundleDisplayName)

Tags: ios, widget, ios14

I created InfoPlist.strings for my iOS 14 Widget and added below. But this doesn't change the widget's name. This worked for iOS 8 Today's widget previously. How do you localize iOS 14 Widget's app name that gets displayed below (south of) the widget?

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "App Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to delete the app and reinstall and the translation finally popped up!!